# Is there anyway to stored res.send() into variable

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

How can store a json result of res.send() in express js into a variable so that we can archive result without display it into html page?

```
this.app.post('/profile', (req, res, next) => {
    let a = somefunction();
    res.status(200).send(a);
 });
```

Comment: have you tried `var response = res.status(200).send(a);`?

Comment: You can save the contents of `a` by converting it to a string with `JSON.stringify(a)`.  Otherwise, the job of `res.send()` is to send an HTTP response with the contents of `a` as the body of the response.  So, `res.send(a)` makes an HTTP response.  That's what it does.  So, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to put the result into textarea in my ejs template

Answer (score 0):

> How can store a json result of res.send() in express js into a variable

Just assign it to a variable like usual:

```
const myResObject = res.status(200).send(a);
```

> (...) without display it into html page?

Not possible. You have no control over what `res` does internally without monkey patching the prototype.

You can modify your view to not display anything at all when `res.send` is called.